# How can I use the $index inside a ng-repeat to enable a class and show a DIV?

Tags: angularjs

I have a set of `<li>` elements.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-class="{current: selected == 100}">
     <a href ng:click="selected=100">ABC</a>
  </li>
  <li ng-class="{current: selected == 101}">
     <a href ng:click="selected=101">DEF</a>
  </li>
  <li ng-class="{current: selected == $index }" 
      ng-repeat="x in [4,5,6,7]">
     <a href ng:click="selected=$index">A{{$index}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When a user clicks on one of the address elements above then then it should, set the value of selected and show one of the `<DIV>` elements below:

```
<div  ng:show="selected == 100">100</div>
<div  ng:show="selected == 101">101</div>
<div ng-repeat="x in [4,5,6,7]" ng:show="selected == $index">{{ $index }}</div>
```

This works for the first two cases.

- When the user clicks ABC then the first `<DIV>` shows 100 and changes color to red.
- When DEF is clicked then 101 shows and DEF changes to red.

However it does not work at all for A0, A1, A2 and A3

- When a user clicks A0, A1, A2 or A3 then the correct  does not show, the selected value is not set and the color of ALL the ng-repeat A0,A1,A2 and A3 turn to red.

This is best shown if you look at this Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/7HMeObplaBkx5R0SntjY?p=preview

Note that at the top I have added `{{ selected }}` as a debug aid at the top. Also the `x in [4,5,6,7]` are just meant to simulate a loop. In real life I have this as `ng-repeat="answer in modal.data.answers"`.

Does anyone know how I can set this up so that the `li` class current is set at the right time and the `DIV` shows at the right time for the A0, A1, A2 and A3 `<li>` and `<DIV>`

Answer (score 205, accepted):

The issue here is that `ng-repeat` creates its own scope, so when you do `selected=$index` it creates a new a `selected` property in that scope rather than altering the existing one. To fix this you have two options:

Change the selected property to a non-primitive (ie object or array, which makes javascript look up the prototype chain) then set a value on that:

```
$scope.selected = {value: 0};

<a ng-click="selected.value = $index">A{{$index}}</a>
```

[See plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KBlOxdGDBxySXHiQD2JP?p=preview)

**or**

Use the `$parent` variable to access the correct property. Though less recommended as it increases coupling between scopes

```
<a ng-click="$parent.selected = $index">A{{$index}}</a>
```

[See plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oWgQs2YPSoCcTGrZsmg4?p=preview)

Comment: They're two separate approaches to the problem. The idea was you could go with which one you prefer.

Answer (score 30):

As johnnyynnoj mentioned **ng-repeat** creates a new scope. I would in fact use a function to set the value. See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZJSB3EQD3AozIpDSOZJh?p=preview)

**JS**:

```
$scope.setSelected = function(selected) {
  $scope.selected = selected;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
{{ selected }}

<ul>
  <li ng-class="{current: selected == 100}">
     <a href ng:click="setSelected(100)">ABC</a>
  </li>
  <li ng-class="{current: selected == 101}">
     <a href ng:click="setSelected(101)">DEF</a>
  </li>
  <li ng-class="{current: selected == $index }" 
      ng-repeat="x in [4,5,6,7]">
     <a href ng:click="setSelected($index)">A{{$index}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div  
  ng:show="selected == 100">
  100        
</div>
<div  
  ng:show="selected == 101">
  101        
</div>
<div ng-repeat="x in [4,5,6,7]" 
  ng:show="selected == $index">
  {{ $index }}        
</div>
```

Comment: Does `ng:click` really work? I thought it was `ng-click`