# Trigger Angular scope id remotely outside of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am looking for some help with a little Angular App.
I have a group of items/images that when a plus icon is clicked, all other items are covered and the selected item is not covered.

I want to now trigger this from outside of the ng-repeat.

I am looking for a way to trigger the cover effect **when clicking on a text link**, as well as the plus icon now used.
 Have it use both options.

So far I have the text triggers fire off a id, that can be used in the app code.

Here is a Working [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/yLyrweaw/).

Here is the [**original question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523109/angular-scope-and-ng-click-ng-show-to-set-multiple-divs) that Avijit Gupta did for this.
Avijit's post is the excepted answer.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

**The nav Text trigger code...**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 navText">
    <ul>
       <li><a href data-id='1' data-ng-click="idLocation($event)">ONE</a></li>
       <li><a href data-id='2' data-ng-click="idLocation($event)">TWO</a></li>
       <li><a href data-id='3' data-ng-click="idLocation($event)">THREE</a></li>
       <li><a href data-id='4' data-ng-click="idLocation($event)">FOUR</a></li>
       <li><a href data-id='5' data-ng-click="idLocation($event)">FIVE</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**The app code...**

```
    // nav text trigger id's
    $scope.idLocation = function (e) {
        ids = $(e.target).data('id');
        console.log(ids); 
    };

  $scope.setToInitialState = function() {
    $scope.blocks.forEach(function(block) {
      $scope.isSelected[block.id] = false;
      $scope.isCovered[block.id] =  false;
    });
  };

  $scope.selectBlock = function(id) {
    $scope.isSelected[id] = !$scope.isSelected[id];
    $scope.isCovered[id] = false;
    if ($scope.isSelected[id]) {
      $scope.blocks.forEach(function(block) {
        if (block.id !== id) {
          $scope.isCovered[block.id] = true;
          $scope.isSelected[block.id] = false;
        } 
      });
    }
    else {
      $scope.setToInitialState();
    }   
  };   

});
```

How it works...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the same ng-repeat in tag li and the same function selectBlock in tag a.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 navText">
        <ul>
           <li ng-repeat="block in blocks"><a href data-ng-click="selectBlock(block.id)">{{block.name}}</a></li>       
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also I add the field name for each element in blocks.

```
$scope.blocks = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'ONE',
        block: "1",
    }, 
    {
        id: '2',
        name: 'TWO',
        block: "2",
    }, 
    {
        id: '3',
        name: 'THREE',
        block: "3",
    }, 
    {
        id: '4',
        name: 'FOUR',
        block: "4",
    }, 
    {
       id: '5',
       name: 'FIVE',
       block: "5"
    }
];
```

Comment: Hello Dj_System.  This did not really answer the question for what I was looking for. But I do appreciate what you suggested. You can see I have answered my own question with an option that works for me.  Thanks AngularJR

Answer (score 0):

**To Answer my own question.**

One way to trigger the cover effect from outside of the ng-repeat.
What I did here was to use the **selectBlock()** in a data-ng-click and just hard code the **ID** into the **selectBlock()**.

Like this...

```
<li><a href data-ng-click="selectBlock('1')">ONE</a></li>
<li><a href data-ng-click="selectBlock('2')">TWO</a></li>
<li><a href data-ng-click="selectBlock('3')">THREE</a></li>
<li><a href data-ng-click="selectBlock('4')">FOUR</a></li>
<li><a href data-ng-click="selectBlock('5')">FIVE</a></li>
```

Here is the demo of it working by clicking the TEXT and the +/- icon.

Working [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/yLyrweaw/3/).

[image]