# how to display bootstrap collapse-panel in a loop using angularJS ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angularJS and trying to add bootstrap collapsible-panel in a loop.
I have written the code below, but the `body` of all the panels is getting displayed under the first panel header.
I need the `body` to be displayed under their corresponding panel headers.
I believe this is happening because of the `<div id="myButton">` is getting called for all the subsequent panel in the loop whenever a click is taking place in `<a href="#myButton">`.
Is there a way I can use a variable value for setting the ID?
Anything like:  `<a href="#{{variable}}">` and `<div id="{{variable}}">`  ?

Code I wrote:

```
<div ng-repeat="ownr in meldHealth.ownerList | orderBy: 'ownr'">
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#myButton" ng-click="getApps(ownr)">{{ownr}}</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="myButton" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <span ng-repeat="word in ownerApps | orderBy: 'word'">
                            <button class="btn btn-default text-blue" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" type="button"
                             ng-click="getDetails(word.name, currOwner)" style="width:250px;">
                            {{word.name}}
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make use of `$index` in Angular

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#myButton{{$index}}" ng-click="getApps(ownr)">{{ownr}}</a>
```

and in your `<div>`

```
<div id="myButton{{$index}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

Rest of the code can pretty much be the same.

Comment: OMG!! such a quick response. @Nikhil..you are genius. I spent 4 hrs on this. Thank you soo much. :)

Comment: :) Glad it helped .. Cheers !

Comment: the Aurelia equivalent uses ${$index} instead of {{$index}}

Answer (score 1):

In order to resolve this duplicate ID issue you can use $index and check the link [How can I use the $index inside a ng-repeat to enable a class and show a DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925355/how-can-i-use-the-index-inside-a-ng-repeat-to-enable-a-class-and-show-a-div)
Example `<span id="{{$index}}"></span>`