# apply CSS class on HTML element inside ng-repeat based on condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make HTML headings active/inactive based on `active` variable. But to set the `active` flag on clicking the heading, I am using the `$index` variable of `ng-repeat` directive:

```
<div ng-init="active = 1">
  <h4 ng-repeat="(key, val) in vm.headings" ng-click="active = $index" ng-class="{'active': active === $index}">
{{key}}
</h4>
</div>
```

Heading object:

```
vm.headings = {
    "HEADING_1": "CONTENT",
    "HEADING_2": "CONTENT",
    "HEADING_3": "CONTENT"
};
```

On first load, one of the headings appear 'active` as set. But on subsequent clicks, it does not give the desired results. All the headings become active on clicking them. [Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/khew5v29/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<h4 ng-repeat="(key, val) in vm.headings" ng-click="selectH($index)" ng-class="{'active': active === $index}">
```

In controller:

```
$scope.selectH= function(index) {
   $scope.active = index; 
};
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: For more details on the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925355/how-can-i-use-the-index-inside-a-ng-repeat-to-enable-a-class-and-show-a-div